# Why is e.Row.DataItem null in RowCreated function of GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Partial HTML source for a GridView (ID: `MyGrid`):

```
...
<tr title="Task is Past Due" style="color:#C00000;background-color:#EBE9E9;">
    <td>
        <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentMain$yourTasksGV$ctl04$btnShowDepend" id="btnShowDepend" title="Click to view Dependencies" class="gvTaskDep btnShowDepend" src="es.png" alt="" />
        <div id="pnlSubTasks" class="pnlSubTasks">
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:DarkRed;">
    </td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">SOMETHING</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">Something</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">Something</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">03-09-2015</td> //<asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="7%" DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    <td class="taskTableColumn">Something</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">Something</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">Something</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">Something</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="taskTableColumn"></td>
    <td class="hideTag">1</td>
    <td class="hideTag">155</td>
</tr>
...
```

When I click on the `btnShowDepend` image to perform some operation, it fails in the GridView `RowCreated` function:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    var k = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Due Date"); //k=null
    DateTime dt;
    DateTime.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Due Date").ToString(), out dt); //e.Row.DataItem = null
    if (dt < DateTime.Today)
    {
        //or do it for a specific cell
        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
    }
}
```

Why is `k` null and how can I modify the code to fix it.

Please note: If it can also be done using JQuery, I would like that solution.

I would like to make the font color RED to any row where the column's `Due Date` is less than today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an ASP.net guy, but with jQuery you could use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) like this:

```
$('#btnShowDepend').on('click', function () {
    var now = Date.now();

    $('td.taskTableColumn').each(function () {
        var date = Date.parse($(this).text());

        // Skip invalid dates
        if (isNaN(date)) return;

        if (date < now) {
            $(this).css({
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

### EDIT:

To cycle through the entire table, turning each row RED if its "6th column" contains a date earlier than today, you can do this like so:

```
$('#btnShowDepend').on('click', function () {
    var now = Date.now();

    $('#myTableId tr').each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        var the6thColumn = $row.find('.my6thColumnClass');
        var date = Date.parse($(the6thColumn).text());

        // Skip invalid dates
        if (isNaN(date)) return;

        if (date < now) {
            $row.css({
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Assuming:

1. The table in question has an id of `myTableId`
2. The "6th column" cells have a class of `my6thColumnClass` like so: `<td class="my6thColumnClass">`.

Comment: Actually I wanted to go there. Is there any way to cycle through a table ('yourTasksGridView') and compare the 6th column (Format: `mm-dd-yyyy`) of each row. if the 6th column on that row is less than today's date, make the entire TR of that table font color to red. I would like to do that to the entire table.

Comment: Updated with another example for ya.

Comment: Thank you. I was working and almost was close to what you had. I think I have to set the `now` because it is undefined.

Comment: Yeah you'd learn a lot more by building the second example yourself based on the first example, but glad I could help.  Feel free to accept my answer if you want ;-)